# VB.NET how to prevent embedded images in the executable

Tags: vb.net, resources

I'm working in a VB.NET application using Visual Studio 2017.

I'm using a lot of images in my project and if I follow the instructions that I've found in the Internet (add images to a resource file) the executable ends up weighting more than 300MB. This is a huge problem because when I want to send updates to the users they have to download every time 300MB instead of just a few KB, and perhaps some additional images.

I would prefer the images to be stored separately from the executable, in the same folder, but this does not seem to be possible because using the resource file and building a release version they all get eaten inside the executable.

(Note that I need the images to show while working on the designer module, so it is not an option to load them all through code using image.fromfile, which would do exactly what I want)

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If the total size of your images is so large, then do not use image resources. Fetch your images from your web site on the fly and cache them on the client side, alternatively store them in a database as BLOBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate class library project in the same solution. A class library project is compiled to a DLL. Include the image resources in this library project and add it as project reference to the main project.

If the image resources don't change, you don't need to re-distribute this DLL.

---

A trick that could enable you to use these resources at design time could be to use satellite assemblies for culture specific resources (I never tried it so). In your case you would have only on single culture.

See:

- [Locating and Using Resources for a Specific Culture (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ckwb4b(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)
- [Localizing a Windows Application with Satellite Assemblies](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59193/Localizing-a-Windows-Application-with-Satellite-As) (article uses C# but should be the same procedure for VB).
- [How to Localize Windows Forms and Change the Language at Runtime](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=174)

Comment: This is working great, but I'm still unable to see the image in the designer module by selecting the image in the "image" property of a picturebox. It only allows me to select an image from the resource file of the form's project, and not from the resource file of the class library.

Comment: I found a way to do this editing the code inside form1.designer.vb and using Me.PictureBox1.Image = ClassLibrary1.My.Resources.(name). However, the comments in this code read "do not modify this code using the code editor". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are making changes to the form in the designer and save it, this code might be replaced by automatically generated code. Try it and see whether your edit remains. You could do that in the constructor or in Form_Load instead.

Comment: You are right, the code that I wrote disappeared after editing in the designer. Any other way to display the image from the class library in the designer of the main project?

Comment: @Kim_Sunwoo  You don't need to modify the Designer code. Insert that code in the Form contructor (`Sub New()`). If you don't have one yet, write it in the code part of the class.